# Phase Shift Between two signals with different unknown frequencies

Tags: python, signals, shift, phase

```html
    Time    Heave   Trim
40.228  -4.057  0.016
40.238  -3.253  0.182
40.248  -3.084  0.12
40.257  -2.957  0.161
40.267  -2.28   0.245
40.277  -2.66   -0.047
40.287  -1.899  0.265
40.297  -1.687  0.141
40.307  -1.349  0.141
40.317  -1.433  -0.026
40.327  -0.46   0.161
40.337  -0.333  0.12
40.347  -0.121  0.057
40.356  0.556   0.203
40.366  0.26    -0.047
40.376  0.26    -0.13
40.386  0.725   -0.067
40.396  1.191   -0.005
40.406  1.021   -0.088
40.416  1.445   -0.005
40.426  1.614   -0.067
40.436  1.529   -0.067
40.446  1.656   -0.109
40.455  1.614   -0.088
40.465  1.233   -0.275
40.475  1.402   -0.171
40.485  1.318   -0.275
40.495  1.825   -0.026
40.505  0.767   -0.358
40.515  0.471   -0.462
40.525  0.514   -0.317
40.535  0.048   -0.421
40.545  0.006   -0.379
40.554  0.387   -0.088
40.564  -0.502  -0.338
40.574  -0.925  -0.358
40.584  -1.306  -0.338
40.594  -1.56   -0.379
40.604  -2.872  -0.608
40.614  -2.534  -0.4
40.624  -3.211  -0.442
40.634  -3.126  -0.379
40.644  -3.422  -0.296
40.653  -3.718  -0.338
40.663  -4.015  -0.254
40.673  -4.65   -0.317
40.683  -4.988  -0.4
40.693  -4.269  0.037
40.703  -5.242  -0.254
40.713  -5.538  -0.275
40.723  -5.581  -0.213
40.733  -5.708  -0.067
40.743  -6.3    -0.296
40.752  -5.919  -0.15
40.762  -6.173  -0.15
40.772  -6.385  -0.15
40.782  -6.3    -0.067
40.792  -6.3    -0.109
40.802  -6.215  -0.067
40.812  -6.3    -0.067
40.822  -6.215  -0.026
40.832  -5.792  0.016
40.842  -5.919  -0.047
40.851  -5.2    0.099
40.861  -5.538  -0.005
40.871  -5.03   0.12
40.881  -4.734  0.078
40.891  -4.396  0.141
40.901  -4.353  0.057
40.911  -4.015  0.099
40.921  -3.338  0.224
40.931  -3.422  0.037
40.941  -2.787  0.182
40.95   -2.576  0.037
40.96   -2.364  0.12
40.97   -1.772  0.182
40.98   -2.026  -0.005
40.99   -1.433  0.057
41  -0.798  0.141
41.01   -0.798  0.12
41.02   -0.756  -0.088
41.03   -0.333  -0.088
41.04   0.344   0.141
41.05   -0.037  -0.067
41.059  1.064   0.224
41.069  0.598   0.037
41.079  0.175   -0.213
41.089  1.148   0.161
41.099  0.429   -0.171
41.109  0.006   -0.4
41.119  1.064   -0.005
41.129  0.725   -0.13
41.139  0.217   -0.317
41.149  -0.206  -0.421
41.158  0.006   -0.338
41.168  -0.248  -0.4
41.178  -0.671  -0.442
41.188  -0.841  -0.483
41.198  -0.925  -0.421
41.208  -0.248  -0.026
41.218  -0.756  -0.213
41.228  -1.772  -0.358
41.238  -2.195  -0.442
41.248  -2.237  -0.317
41.257  -2.407  -0.254
41.267  -3.38   -0.546
41.277  -3.211  -0.358
41.287  -3.507  -0.358
41.297  -4.226  -0.462
41.307  -4.099  -0.338
41.317  -4.311  -0.338
41.327  -4.861  -0.483
41.337  -4.988  -0.317
41.347  -5.03   -0.254
41.356  -4.438  0.078
41.366  -5.496  -0.275
41.376  -5.369  -0.192
41.386  -5.708  -0.192
41.396  -5.411  -0.067
41.406  -5.496  -0.13
41.416  -5.496  -0.026
41.426  -5.708  -0.13
41.436  -5.75   -0.13
41.446  -5.496  -0.13
41.455  -5.411  -0.026
41.465  -5.284  -0.005
41.475  -5.115  -0.005
41.485  -4.607  0.182
41.495  -4.607  0.078
41.505  -4.48   0.057
41.515  -4.057  0.12
41.525  -4.057  0.037
41.535  -3.507  0.078
41.545  -3.422  0.037
41.554  -2.703  0.245
41.564  -2.449  0.224
41.574  -2.026  0.141
41.584  -1.899  0.182
41.594  -1.179  0.265
41.604  -1.729  -0.005
41.614  -1.01   0.078
41.624  -0.46   0.161
41.634  -0.375  0.078
41.644  0.344   0.265
41.653  0.133   -0.005
41.663  0.048   -0.067
41.673  0.81    0.057
41.683  0.64    -0.047
41.693  0.979   -0.067
41.703  0.767   -0.13
41.713  0.894   -0.15
41.723  1.191   -0.109
41.733  1.402   -0.13
41.743  1.021   -0.275
41.752  1.402   -0.192
41.762  0.979   -0.254
41.772  1.106   -0.213
41.782  0.767   -0.317
41.792  0.344   -0.4
41.802  0.556   -0.275
41.812  0.26    -0.254
41.822  -0.037  -0.338
41.832  -0.418  -0.421
41.842  -0.46   -0.317
41.851  -0.121  -0.047
41.861  -1.391  -0.358
41.871  -1.983  -0.566
41.881  -2.153  -0.4
41.891  -2.026  -0.213
41.901  -2.364  -0.296
41.911  -2.787  -0.317
41.921  -3.422  -0.442
41.931  -3.888  -0.4
41.941  -3.93   -0.421
41.95   -3.972  -0.275
41.96   -4.353  -0.275
41.97   -4.819  -0.338
41.98   -4.396  -0.088
41.99   -5.115  -0.296
42  -4.819  -0.192
42.01   -5.369  -0.275
42.02   -5.2    -0.171
42.03   -5.581  -0.15
42.04   -5.454  -0.088
42.05   -5.327  -0.088
42.059  -5.496  -0.067
42.069  -5.623  -0.13
42.079  -4.946  0.057
42.089  -5.369  -0.109
42.099  -5.073  -0.005
42.109  -4.523  0.161
42.119  -4.734  0.016
42.129  -4.819  -0.088
42.139  -4.269  -0.047
42.149  -3.888  0.12
42.158  -3.845  0.078
42.168  -3.041  0.161
42.178  -2.83   0.265
42.188  -2.618  0.12
42.198  -1.983  0.307
42.208  -1.983  0.141
42.218  -1.306  0.224
42.228  -0.968  0.182
42.238  -0.841  0.078
42.248  -0.544  0.099
42.257  -0.671  -0.088
42.267  -0.418  -0.109
42.277  0.387   -0.026
42.287  0.725   0.037
42.297  1.021   0.057
42.307  1.318   0.037
42.317  0.387   -0.4
42.327  1.487   -0.026
42.337  1.487   -0.171
42.347  1.572   -0.213
42.356  1.275   -0.275
42.366  1.91    -0.047
42.376  1.868   -0.15
42.386  1.952   -0.15
42.396  1.995   -0.192
42.406  2.418   0.161
42.416  1.064   -0.442
42.426  1.318   -0.317
42.436  1.656   -0.047
42.446  0.683   -0.338
42.455  0.302   -0.462
42.465  0.387   -0.338
42.475  0.006   -0.338
42.485  -0.206  -0.234
42.495  -0.037  -0.067
42.505  -1.264  -0.504
42.515  -2.153  -0.67
42.525  -1.729  -0.317
42.535  -2.491  -0.462
42.545  -2.914  -0.525
42.554  -3.38   -0.483
42.564  -3.295  -0.317
42.574  -3.761  -0.317
42.584  -3.972  -0.254
42.594  -4.438  -0.338
42.604  -5.115  -0.442
42.614  -4.988  -0.254
42.624  -5.284  -0.296
42.634  -5.454  -0.296
42.644  -6.046  -0.338
42.653  -6.046  -0.358
42.663  -5.961  -0.171
42.673  -6.131  -0.213
42.683  -6.427  -0.213
42.693  -6.3    -0.15
42.703  -6.088  -0.005
42.713  -6.131  0.016
42.723  -6.173  0.016
42.733  -6.173  -0.047
42.743  -5.919  0.057
42.752  -6.258  -0.13
42.762  -5.623  0.078
42.772  -5.369  0.078
42.782  -5.581  -0.005
42.792  -5.242  0.057
42.802  -4.48   0.265
42.812  -4.903  -0.026
42.822  -4.353  0.078
42.832  -3.888  0.265
42.842  -3.845  0.12
42.851  -3.211  0.141
42.861  -2.576  0.265
42.871  -2.787  0.099
42.881  -2.66   0.057
42.891  -2.195  0.099
42.901  -1.518  0.12
42.911  -2.026  -0.109
42.921  -1.095  0.057
42.931  -0.925  0.057
42.941  -0.248  0.141
42.95   -0.544  -0.005
42.96   -0.037  0.016
42.97   0.09    -0.026
42.98   -0.037  -0.088
42.99   0.26    -0.067
43  0.09    -0.15
43.01   0.302   -0.171
43.02   0.598   -0.13
43.03   0.387   -0.171
43.04   0.26    -0.317
43.05   0.387   -0.192
43.059  -0.164  -0.421
43.069  0.26    -0.213
43.079  -0.248  -0.296
43.089  -0.291  -0.234
43.099  -0.418  -0.254
43.109  -0.418  -0.192
43.119  -1.306  -0.4
43.129  -1.391  -0.338
43.139  -2.11   -0.462
43.149  -1.899  -0.296
43.158  -2.28   -0.275
43.168  -2.83   -0.4
43.178  -2.957  -0.338
43.188  -3.422  -0.317
43.198  -3.93   -0.483
43.208  -3.803  -0.296
43.218  -4.396  -0.421
43.228  -4.903  -0.442
43.238  -4.607  -0.234
43.248  -4.861  -0.254
43.257  -5.073  -0.296
43.267  -5.496  -0.379
43.277  -5.454  -0.234
43.287  -5.877  -0.317
43.297  -5.792  -0.192
43.307  -5.708  -0.109
43.317  -5.919  -0.192
43.327  -5.877  -0.13
43.337  -5.75   -0.067
43.347  -6.131  -0.192
43.356  -5.834  -0.088
43.366  -5.708  -0.088
43.376  -5.327  0.057
43.386  -5.327  -0.005
43.396  -5.411  -0.109
43.406  -4.776  0.037
43.416  -4.396  0.037
43.426  -4.353  0.016
43.436  -4.142  0.099
43.446  -3.634  0.12
43.455  -3.211  0.161
43.465  -3.041  0.12
43.475  -2.703  0.099
43.485  -2.618  -0.005
43.495  -2.026  0.016
43.505  -1.476  0.078
43.515  -1.095  0.161
43.525  -1.01   0.037
43.535  -1.095  -0.13
43.545  0.217   0.349
43.554  0.471   0.161
43.564  0.344   0.016
43.574  -0.079  -0.254
43.584  0.852   -0.026
43.594  1.445   0.057
43.604  0.725   -0.234
43.614  1.106   -0.254
43.624  1.402   -0.213
43.634  2.122   -0.026
43.644  1.656   -0.213
43.653  1.825   -0.192
43.663  1.487   -0.4
43.673  2.037   -0.192
43.683  1.825   -0.213
43.693  2.206   0.099
43.703  1.445   -0.317
43.713  0.852   -0.483
43.723  0.598   -0.546
43.733  1.318   -0.234
43.743  0.556   -0.421
43.752  0.302   -0.358
43.762  0.048   -0.358
43.772  -0.714  -0.546
43.782  -0.714  -0.4
43.792  -0.968  -0.338
43.802  -1.687  -0.442
43.812  -1.729  -0.358
43.822  -2.745  -0.587
43.832  -2.787  -0.462
43.842  -2.83   -0.317
43.851  -2.914  -0.234
43.861  -3.718  -0.462
43.871  -3.93   -0.338
43.881  -4.057  -0.358
43.891  -4.48   -0.317
43.901  -4.353  -0.254
43.911  -4.819  -0.317
43.921  -4.819  -0.15
43.931  -4.692  -0.109
43.941  -5.327  -0.234
43.95   -5.411  -0.234
43.96   -5.961  -0.358
43.97   -5.242  -0.067
43.98   -5.496  -0.109
43.99   -5.665  -0.15
44  -5.073  0.057
44.01   -5.2    -0.047
44.02   -5.284  -0.047
44.03   -4.903  0.037
44.04   -4.776  0.037
44.05   -4.776  -0.005
44.059  -4.311  0.099
44.069  -4.226  0.037
44.079  -3.041  0.39
44.089  -3.803  0.057
44.099  -3.549  -0.005
44.109  -2.83   0.203
44.119  -2.364  0.265
44.129  -2.026  0.203
44.139  -1.983  0.161
44.149  -1.814  0.099
44.158  -1.433  0.078
44.168  -0.798  0.161
44.178  -0.502  0.099
44.188  -0.121  0.182
44.198  -0.291  -0.026
44.208  0.514   0.224
44.218  0.387   0.016
44.228  0.387   -0.047
44.238  0.767   0.016
44.248  0.64    -0.109
44.257  1.064   -0.067
44.267  1.233   -0.026
44.277  1.36    -0.047
44.287  1.36    -0.109
44.297  1.275   -0.088
44.307  1.106   -0.275
44.317  1.148   -0.192
44.327  0.852   -0.254
44.337  0.81    -0.296
44.347  0.81    -0.234
44.356  0.683   -0.234
44.366  0.514   -0.275
44.376  0.217   -0.296
44.386  0.006   -0.213
44.396  -0.671  -0.421
44.406  -0.925  -0.4
44.416  -1.222  -0.379
44.426  -1.687  -0.421
44.436  -1.729  -0.358
44.446  -2.237  -0.358
44.455  -2.491  -0.358
44.465  -2.872  -0.358
44.475  -3.507  -0.421
44.485  -3.888  -0.442
44.495  -4.311  -0.421
44.505  -4.269  -0.338
44.515  -4.65   -0.317
44.525  -4.861  -0.317
44.535  -4.988  -0.296
44.545  -5.284  -0.338
44.554  -5.327  -0.234
44.564  -5.327  -0.192
44.574  -6.004  -0.317
44.584  -5.877  -0.192
44.594  -6.173  -0.317
44.604  -5.961  -0.13
44.614  -6.3    -0.234
44.624  -6.046  -0.088
44.634  -5.792  -0.047
44.644  -5.919  -0.047
44.653  -5.708  -0.047
44.663  -5.496  0.016
44.673  -5.581  -0.026
44.683  -5.75   -0.254
44.693  -4.65   0.224
44.703  -4.776  0.037
44.713  -5.073  -0.13
44.723  -4.523  -0.026
44.733  -4.396  -0.088
44.743  -3.845  0.078
44.752  -3.761  0.016
44.762  -3.168  0.12
44.772  -2.576  0.078
44.782  -1.56   0.557
44.792  -2.237  0.057
44.802  -2.449  -0.171
44.812  -1.899  -0.109
44.822  -0.375  0.536
44.832  -0.418  0.203
44.842  -0.671  -0.005
44.851  -0.164  0.161
44.861  -0.248  -0.005
44.871  0.048   0.016
44.881  0.302   -0.067
44.891  0.217   -0.15
44.901  0.471   0.016
44.911  -0.164  -0.4
44.921  0.683   -0.109
44.931  0.09    -0.317
44.941  1.275   0.078
44.95   0.471   -0.296
44.96   0.767   -0.15
44.97   0.429   -0.254
44.98   0.429   -0.234
44.99   0.344   -0.234
45  -0.079  -0.275
45.01   -0.502  -0.483
45.02   -0.502  -0.379
45.03   -1.052  -0.462
45.04   -1.095  -0.421
45.05   -1.391  -0.4
45.059  -1.729  -0.442
45.069  -1.729  -0.317
45.079  -2.11   -0.338
45.089  -2.957  -0.525
45.099  -2.999  -0.462
45.109  -2.914  -0.234
45.119  -3.676  -0.4
45.129  -4.523  -0.608
45.139  -3.93   -0.317
45.149  -4.269  -0.317
45.158  -4.226  -0.234
45.168  -4.903  -0.379
45.178  -4.734  -0.13
45.188  -5.581  -0.421
45.198  -5.242  -0.213
45.208  -5.496  -0.213
45.218  -5.623  -0.234
45.228  -5.454  -0.109
45.238  -5.623  -0.13
45.248  -6.004  -0.254
45.257  -5.75   -0.15
45.267  -5.75   -0.13
45.277  -5.792  -0.192
45.287  -5.157  0.037
45.297  -5.369  -0.005
45.307  -5.454  -0.109
45.317  -5.073  -0.005
45.327  -4.269  0.099
45.337  -4.776  -0.109
45.347  -4.057  0.141
45.356  -4.142  -0.005
45.366  -4.015  -0.026
45.376  -3.084  0.224
45.386  -3.972  -0.254
45.396  -3.084  0.016
45.406  -2.449  0.12
45.416  -2.407  0.016
45.426  -1.772  0.182
45.436  -1.518  0.099
45.446  -1.306  0.037
45.455  -1.01   0.078
45.465  -0.756  0.099
45.475  -0.544  0.037
45.485  -0.46   -0.067
45.495  -0.121  -0.047
45.505  -0.121  -0.13
45.515  0.429   -0.005
45.525  0.64    0.016
45.535  0.387   -0.171
45.545  0.514   -0.15
45.554  0.683   -0.13
45.564  0.725   -0.13
45.574  0.429   -0.254
45.584  0.471   -0.275
45.594  0.81    -0.213
45.604  0.725   -0.15
45.614  0.175   -0.379
45.624  0.048   -0.338
45.634  0.133   -0.317
45.644  -0.206  -0.338
45.653  -0.671  -0.421
45.663  -0.841  -0.379
45.673  -0.671  -0.296
45.683  -1.095  -0.358
45.693  -1.687  -0.379
45.703  -1.814  -0.338
45.713  -2.068  -0.234
45.723  -2.491  -0.338
45.733  -2.999  -0.358
45.743  -3.253  -0.358
45.752  -3.592  -0.379
45.762  -4.099  -0.483
45.772  -4.353  -0.379
45.782  -4.226  -0.254
45.792  -4.819  -0.358
45.802  -4.861  -0.254
45.812  -5.073  -0.254
45.822  -5.581  -0.275
45.832  -5.665  -0.275
45.842  -5.284  -0.067
45.851  -5.834  -0.213
45.861  -5.665  -0.088
45.871  -6.215  -0.213
45.881  -5.284  0.161
45.891  -6.131  -0.13
45.901  -6.173  -0.088
45.911  -5.75   0.078
45.921  -6.131  -0.13
45.931  -5.665  0.057
45.941  -6.088  -0.109
45.95   -5.284  0.182
45.96   -4.946  0.161
45.97   -5.496  -0.171
45.98   -4.607  0.099
45.99   -4.523  0.12
46  -4.184  0.12
46.01   -4.057  0.016
46.02   -3.888  -0.067
46.03   -3.126  0.141
46.04   -2.999  0.057
46.05   -2.322  0.203
46.059  -1.941  0.39
46.069  -1.729  0.224
46.079  -1.264  0.265
46.089  -1.602  -0.026
46.099  -0.925  0.016
46.109  -0.206  0.265
46.119  -0.671  -0.109
46.129  0.006   0.057
46.139  0.26    -0.005
46.149  0.048   -0.13
46.158  0.852   0.161
46.168  0.81    -0.026
46.178  0.514   -0.15
46.188  0.64    -0.192
46.198  0.894   -0.15
46.208  0.64    -0.296
46.218  0.852   -0.275
46.228  0.767   -0.296
46.238  1.275   -0.15
46.248  0.683   -0.338
46.257  0.894   -0.213
46.267  0.387   -0.358
46.277  0.09    -0.525
46.287  -0.121  -0.442
46.297  0.471   -0.15
46.307  -0.248  -0.358
46.317  -0.587  -0.358
46.327  -0.798  -0.4
46.337  -1.476  -0.462
46.347  -1.645  -0.379
46.356  -1.772  -0.379
46.366  -2.449  -0.483
46.376  -2.787  -0.483
46.386  -3.126  -0.483
46.396  -2.787  -0.213
46.406  -3.507  -0.442
46.416  -3.507  -0.338
46.426  -3.549  -0.338
46.436  -4.438  -0.379
46.446  -4.607  -0.379
46.455  -5.284  -0.525
46.465  -4.903  -0.275
46.475  -4.776  -0.192
46.485  -5.327  -0.234
46.495  -5.623  -0.275
46.505  -5.581  -0.275
46.515  -5.496  -0.15
46.525  -5.834  -0.254
46.535  -5.581  -0.15
46.545  -5.538  -0.067
46.554  -5.496  -0.067
46.564  -5.708  -0.171
46.574  -5.073  0.016
46.584  -5.115  -0.005
46.594  -5.2    -0.109
46.604  -4.861  -0.005
46.614  -4.607  0.037
46.624  -4.565  0.037
46.634  -4.142  0.078
46.644  -3.549  0.245
46.653  -3.465  0.161
46.663  -3.549  0.016
46.673  -2.914  0.141
46.683  -3.084  -0.026
46.693  -2.322  0.141
46.703  -1.983  0.141
46.713  -1.645  0.12
46.723  -1.56   -0.047
46.733  -1.095  0.078
46.743  -0.798  0.12
46.752  -0.883  -0.088
46.762  -0.629  -0.026
46.772  -0.079  -0.005
46.782  -0.037  0.016
46.792  0.344   -0.005
46.802  0.133   -0.109
46.812  0.175   -0.13
46.822  0.344   -0.15
46.832  0.344   -0.15
46.842  0.429   -0.213
46.851  0.514   -0.13
46.861  0.852   -0.088
46.871  0.556   -0.317
46.881  0.429   -0.275
46.891  0.344   -0.317
46.901  0.09    -0.338
46.911  -0.121  -0.4
46.921  -0.079  -0.338
46.931  -0.206  -0.296
46.941  -0.671  -0.4
46.95   -0.671  -0.275
46.96   -1.349  -0.462
46.97   -1.391  -0.379
46.98   -1.814  -0.421
46.99   -1.264  -0.047
47  -2.534  -0.379
47.01   -3.338  -0.629
47.02   -2.914  -0.4
47.03   -3.126  -0.358
47.04   -3.592  -0.338
47.05   -3.888  -0.338
47.059  -4.142  -0.379
47.069  -4.269  -0.254
47.079  -4.776  -0.4
47.089  -4.607  -0.213
47.099  -5.284  -0.296
47.109  -5.115  -0.234
47.119  -5.157  -0.171
47.129  -5.581  -0.213
47.139  -5.327  -0.067
47.149  -5.496  -0.067
47.158  -5.877  -0.254
47.168  -5.708  -0.109
47.178  -5.581  -0.067
47.188  -5.369  0.016
47.198  -5.284  0.099
47.208  -4.438  0.307
47.218  -4.903  0.203
47.228  -5.03   -0.005
47.238  -5.115  -0.088
47.248  -4.65   0.078
47.257  -4.48   0.016
47.267  -4.523  -0.026
47.277  -3.845  0.203
47.287  -3.634  0.12
47.297  -3.465  0.12
47.307  -2.999  0.286
47.317  -2.83   0.099
47.327  -2.322  0.245
47.337  -1.856  0.245
47.347  -1.941  0.078
47.356  -1.899  0.037
47.366  -1.56   -0.005
47.376  -1.56   -0.213
47.386  -1.306  -0.026
47.396  -0.375  0.057
47.406  -0.164  0.265
47.416  0.006   0.12
47.426  0.006   0.016
47.436  -0.037  -0.109
47.446  -0.206  -0.171
47.455  0.471   -0.047
47.465  0.556   -0.005
47.475  0.175   -0.254
47.485  0.387   -0.192
47.495  0.006   -0.358
47.505  0.471   -0.234
47.515  0.175   -0.338
47.525  0.302   -0.275
47.535  -0.037  -0.317
47.545  -0.333  -0.379
47.554  -0.037  -0.254
47.564  -0.502  -0.379
47.574  -0.714  -0.421
47.584  -0.544  -0.296
47.594  -1.052  -0.462
47.604  -1.01   -0.213
47.614  -1.222  -0.13
47.624  -1.856  -0.317
47.634  -2.153  -0.4
47.644  -2.068  -0.338
47.653  -2.83   -0.504
47.663  -3.126  -0.442
47.673  -3.041  -0.358
47.683  -3.507  -0.4
47.693  -3.38   -0.234
47.703  -3.634  -0.213
47.713  -3.253  0.037
47.723  -3.888  -0.213
47.733  -4.184  -0.213
47.743  -4.607  -0.338
47.752  -4.353  -0.13
47.762  -4.438  -0.109
47.772  -4.438  -0.088
47.782  -4.776  -0.192
47.792  -4.311  0.057
47.802  -4.523  -0.026
47.812  -4.396  0.057
47.822  -4.311  0.057
47.832  -4.692  -0.067
47.842  -4.438  0.016
47.851  -4.353  -0.047
47.861  -4.099  0.037
47.871  -3.888  0.016
47.881  -3.676  0.078
47.891  -3.718  -0.005
47.901  -3.211  0.099
47.911  -3.084  0.099
47.921  -2.534  0.182
47.931  -2.068  0.245
47.941  -2.153  0.182
47.95   -2.322  0.057
47.96   -1.645  0.141
47.97   -1.814  0.016
47.98   -1.349  0.057
47.99   -1.01   0.078
48  -0.671  0.099
48.01   -0.418  0.099
48.02   -0.248  0.016
48.03   0.217   0.099
48.04   0.387   0.057
48.05   0.429   0.037
48.059  0.683   -0.005
48.069  0.725   0.016
48.079  0.81    -0.026
48.089  0.556   -0.13
48.099  0.979   -0.047
48.109  0.937   -0.109
48.119  1.021   -0.15
48.129  0.852   -0.109
48.139  0.894   -0.192
48.149  0.048   -0.421
48.158  0.429   -0.317
48.168  0.133   -0.338
48.178  0.006   -0.4
48.188  0.09    -0.296
48.198  -0.333  -0.358
48.208  -0.418  -0.296
48.218  -0.968  -0.338
48.228  -1.264  -0.379
48.238  -1.814  -0.462
48.248  -1.983  -0.338
48.257  -2.618  -0.504
48.267  -2.618  -0.338
48.277  -2.999  -0.358
48.287  -3.422  -0.421
48.297  -3.888  -0.421
48.307  -4.226  -0.421
48.317  -4.142  -0.317
48.327  -4.692  -0.4
48.337  -5.157  -0.442
48.347  -5.073  -0.421
48.356  -5.665  -0.4
48.366  -5.708  -0.296
48.376  -5.877  -0.338
48.386  -6.3    -0.4
48.396  -6.131  -0.234
48.406  -6.215  -0.067
48.416  -6.342  -0.234
48.426  -6.554  -0.15
48.436  -6.681  -0.13
48.446  -6.427  -0.171
48.455  -6.385  -0.067
48.465  -6.723  -0.13
48.475  -6.512  -0.005
48.485  -6.3    -0.005
48.495  -6.554  -0.109
48.505  -5.792  0.161
48.515  -6.173  -0.088
48.525  -5.665  0.037
48.535  -5.538  -0.005
48.545  -4.946  0.141
48.554  -4.776  0.182
48.564  -4.692  0.161
48.574  -4.65   0.057
48.584  -3.888  0.203
48.594  -3.888  0.12
48.604  -3.126  0.39
48.614  -2.83   0.349
48.624  -2.787  0.12
48.634  -2.449  0.12
48.644  -2.068  0.161
48.653  -2.576  -0.192
48.663  -1.306  0.203
48.673  -1.179  0.12
48.683  -1.349  -0.026
48.693  -0.883  0.037
48.703  -0.248  0.182
48.713  -0.756  -0.15
48.723  -0.502  -0.067
48.733  -0.121  -0.067
48.743  -0.164  -0.088
48.752  -0.164  -0.13
48.762  -0.46   -0.254
48.772  -0.248  -0.213
48.782  -0.291  -0.254
48.792  0.133   -0.13
48.802  -0.121  -0.275
48.812  -0.121  -0.234
48.822  -0.587  -0.338
48.832  -0.629  -0.338
48.842  -1.052  -0.442
48.851  -1.095  -0.358
48.861  -1.433  -0.462
48.871  -1.602  -0.379
48.881  -1.476  -0.275
48.891  -2.237  -0.4
48.901  -2.491  -0.442
48.911  -2.11   -0.254
48.921  -2.872  -0.317
48.931  -2.957  -0.296
48.941  -3.422  -0.296
48.95   -3.676  -0.317
48.96   -4.184  -0.504
48.97   -4.311  -0.338
48.98   -4.692  -0.4
48.99   -4.776  -0.4
49  -4.396  -0.171
49.01   -4.861  -0.275
49.02   -5.157  -0.234
49.03   -4.48   0.078
49.04   -5.496  -0.234
49.05   -6.004  -0.358
49.059  -5.623  -0.213
49.069  -5.411  -0.109
49.079  -5.961  -0.296
49.089  -5.961  -0.234
49.099  -5.581  -0.088
49.109  -5.411  -0.067
49.119  -5.496  -0.088
49.129  -5.03   0.037
49.139  -5.2    -0.088
49.149  -4.65   0.057
49.158  -4.438  0.057
49.168  -4.269  0.078
49.178  -3.803  0.12
49.188  -4.311  -0.109
49.198  -3.592  0.016
49.208  -3.084  0.12
49.218  -2.999  0.037
49.228  -2.491  0.161
49.238  -1.899  0.161
49.248  -1.687  0.224
49.257  -1.602  0.037
49.267  -1.137  0.161
49.277  -1.01   0.037
49.287  -0.671  0.016
49.297  -0.333  0.078
49.307  -0.121  0.099
49.317  0.048   0.016
49.327  1.021   0.286
49.337  0.175   -0.067
49.347  0.64    -0.026
49.356  0.683   -0.067
49.366  0.852   -0.067
49.376  0.683   -0.171
49.386  0.64    -0.192
49.396  0.81    -0.192
49.406  0.81    -0.15
49.416  0.852   -0.213
49.426  0.725   -0.234
49.436  0.683   -0.213
49.446  0.344   -0.338
49.455  0.09    -0.358
49.465  0.217   -0.317
49.475  -0.121  -0.317
49.485  -0.587  -0.483
49.495  -0.714  -0.317
49.505  -0.841  -0.296
49.515  -1.095  -0.296
49.525  -1.687  -0.379
49.535  -2.11   -0.442
49.545  -2.237  -0.338
49.554  -2.83   -0.421
49.564  -3.041  -0.379
49.574  -3.338  -0.338
49.584  -3.972  -0.421
49.594  -3.845  -0.296
49.604  -4.353  -0.379
49.614  -4.311  -0.234
49.624  -4.946  -0.338
49.634  -5.115  -0.338
49.644  -5.961  -0.504
49.653  -5.538  -0.296
49.663  -5.454  -0.171
49.673  -5.538  -0.15
49.683  -5.75   -0.13
49.693  -5.877  -0.109
49.703  -6.173  -0.192
49.713  -6.131  -0.192
49.723  -6.004  -0.088
49.733  -5.961  -0.005
49.743  -6.088  -0.109
49.752  -6.173  -0.171
49.762  -5.75   -0.067
49.772  -5.538  -0.026
49.782  -5.75   -0.192
49.792  -5.03   0.057
49.802  -4.607  0.224
49.812  -3.972  0.307
49.822  -4.184  0.141
49.832  -3.718  0.328
49.842  -4.015  0.057
49.851  -3.084  0.203
49.861  -2.872  0.161
49.871  -3.041  -0.005
49.881  -2.491  0.078
49.891  -2.195  0.099
49.901  -1.349  0.182
49.911  -1.306  0.12
49.921  -1.052  0.099
49.931  -0.798  -0.005
49.941  -0.587  0.016
49.95   -0.248  0.037
49.96   -0.037  -0.047
49.97   0.598   0.099
49.98   0.64    0.099
49.99   0.725   -0.026
50  1.402   0.307
50.01   0.683   -0.171
50.02   1.36    -0.047
50.03   0.894   -0.213
50.04   0.852   -0.234
50.05   1.91    0.141
50.059  1.191   -0.109
50.069  0.894   -0.254
50.079  0.683   -0.296
50.089  1.021   -0.234
50.099  0.683   -0.296
50.109  0.302   -0.338
50.119  0.048   -0.317
50.129  -0.206  -0.4
50.139  -0.756  -0.462
50.149  -1.01   -0.442
50.158  -1.222  -0.483
50.168  -1.095  -0.275
50.178  -1.941  -0.462
50.188  -1.856  -0.254
50.198  -2.026  -0.254
50.208  -2.999  -0.462
50.218  -3.041  -0.379
50.228  -3.422  -0.338
50.238  -3.465  -0.234
50.248  -3.718  -0.275
50.257  -4.226  -0.275
50.267  -4.353  -0.213
50.277  -4.861  -0.338
50.287  -4.903  -0.109
50.297  -4.946  -0.067
50.307  -5.2    -0.15
50.317  -5.792  -0.234
50.327  -6.088  -0.296
50.337  -5.75   -0.067
50.347  -6.046  -0.171
50.356  -5.75   -0.067
50.366  -6.258  -0.171
50.376  -6.046  -0.109
50.386  -6.215  -0.213
50.396  -6.004  -0.026
50.406  -6.004  -0.088
50.416  -5.581  0.037
50.426  -5.327  0.078
50.436  -5.03   0.12
50.446  -5.369  -0.005
50.455  -4.903  0.037
50.465  -4.861  -0.005
50.475  -4.353  0.099
50.485  -3.93   0.12
50.495  -4.142  0.016
50.505  -3.465  0.12
50.515  -3.126  0.141
50.525  -2.83   0.182
50.535  -2.703  0.099
50.545  -2.407  -0.005
50.554  -2.364  -0.005
50.564  -1.645  0.057
50.574  -1.518  0.057
50.584  -1.179  0.057
50.594  -0.883  0.057
50.604  -0.671  -0.005
50.614  -0.587  0.037
50.624  -0.587  -0.15
50.634  -0.164  -0.067
50.644  -0.248  -0.15
50.653  -0.164  -0.15
50.663  0.217   -0.15
50.673  0.133   -0.15
50.683  0.09    -0.317
50.693  0.471   -0.13
50.703  -0.037  -0.254
50.713  -0.291  -0.358
50.723  0.133   -0.234
50.733  -0.206  -0.379
50.743  0.006   -0.254
50.752  -0.756  -0.442
50.762  -1.095  -0.546
50.772  -0.46   -0.234
50.782  -0.756  -0.234
50.792  -1.306  -0.338
50.802  -1.476  -0.317
50.812  -1.941  -0.358
50.822  -2.28   -0.4
50.832  -2.28   -0.317
50.842  -2.491  -0.317
50.851  -2.83   -0.296
50.861  -3.38   -0.421
50.871  -3.253  -0.234
50.881  -3.761  -0.338
50.891  -3.718  -0.234
50.901  -4.142  -0.275
50.911  -3.93   -0.067
50.921  -4.607  -0.296
50.931  -4.819  -0.296
50.941  -5.2    -0.338
50.95   -4.142  0.265
50.96   -4.903  -0.088
50.97   -5.2    -0.005
50.98   -5.2    -0.067
50.99   -4.607  0.182
51  -5.581  -0.234
51.01   -5.623  -0.15
51.02   -5.708  -0.15
51.03   -5.073  0.141
51.04   -5.411  -0.067
51.05   -5.073  0.037
51.059  -4.988  0.245
51.069  -5.242  -0.13
51.079  -4.607  0.12
51.089  -4.734  -0.047
51.099  -4.226  0.12
51.109  -3.845  0.161
51.119  -3.93   0.12
51.129  -3.465  0.141
51.139  -3.253  0.099
51.149  -3.338  -0.026
51.158  -2.914  0.037
51.168  -2.449  0.182
51.178  -2.449  0.078
51.188  -2.364  -0.026
51.198  -1.899  0.016
51.208  -1.602  0.057
51.218  -1.349  0.141
51.228  -1.349  0.037
51.238  -1.179  -0.005
51.248  -0.883  -0.005
51.257  -0.841  -0.047
51.267  -0.883  -0.15
51.277  -0.671  -0.109
51.287  -0.798  -0.213
51.297  -0.629  -0.171
51.307  -0.587  -0.234
51.317  -0.46   -0.234
51.327  -0.756  -0.296
51.337  -0.798  -0.254
51.347  -0.544  -0.171
51.356  -0.798  -0.234
51.366  -0.841  -0.234
51.376  -1.264  -0.4
51.386  -1.687  -0.462
51.396  -1.687  -0.379
51.406  -2.237  -0.483
51.416  -2.237  -0.379
51.426  -2.618  -0.421
51.436  -2.449  -0.296
51.446  -2.618  -0.296
51.455  -3.676  -0.504
51.465  -3.168  -0.254
51.475  -3.422  -0.275
51.485  -3.888  -0.358
51.495  -4.057  -0.296
51.505  -4.311  -0.275
51.515  -4.946  -0.338
51.525  -5.157  -0.296
51.535  -5.538  -0.358
51.545  -5.157  -0.171
51.554  -5.2    -0.15
51.564  -5.708  -0.275
51.574  -5.708  -0.213
51.584  -5.623  -0.13
```

I've got two signals recorded from an experiment, plotted against the time. I'm trying to determine the phase shift between them, but I've only find example for similar frequency.

The two signals look like this:

[image]

I'm wondering if anyone would have a practical way to determine the phase shift in python?
thanks
[excel data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRJ8u.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the dataset in a reproducible format?

Comment: I'm not sure phase shift makes any sense for signals with different frequencies.

Comment: Phase shift signifies how much you'd have to shift one signal to make it align with another. You cannot align signals that have completely different shape.

Comment: @matszwecja the frequencies seem similar, the amplitude shouldn't matter. But yes, having the raw data would definitely help to clear that up

Comment: @mozway the title and question both explicitly mention differing frequencies, and they'd have to be exactly the same, not even similiar.

Comment: Fair point, then more details are really needed. Voting to close for lack of debugging details.

Comment: @matszwecja.   different frequencies are fine if they are integer multiples of each other...

Comment: The signals correspond to heave amplitude and pitch amplitude (for a vessel) from a tow tank experiment for a vessel. I would need the phase to translate the motion from a point on the vessel to another.

Comment: An image is not reproducible (and there is likely not enough points anyway), you must provide **text**

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the data for the signals but there is over 1000 data point. If the orange signal correspond to the pitch amplitude and the bleu one to the heave amplitude, i would need the phase between the two for the motion translation after

Comment: I've added some data for it, its not all the points but hope it can give more information

Answer (score 0):

Let's first note that your signals do have the same frequency, just a different amplitude and phase.

You could try to perform a cross-correlation of your two curves with `scipy.signal`'s [`correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) and [`correlation_lags`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlation_lags.html):

```
correlation = signal.correlate(df['Heave'], [df['Trim'], df.index], mode='full')
lags = signal.correlation_lags(df['Heave'].size, df['Trim'].size, mode='full')
lag = lags[np.argmax(correlation)]
```

Output: `17` (units of time, which you need to multiply by the time step, here 0.01)

And indeed, if we shift the Trim by 17 units, it aligns with the Heave:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer, I'll try to correct my code.

Comment: Glad this worked out for you, but generally we do not permit users to post "thank you" messages as answers. You can upvote answers and accept answers to show appreciation